# Where to put where() for a query looking for a lightswitch field

Tags: query, lightswitch

Struggling with syntax here. I'm trying to query entries in the "resources" section, ordered by postDate desc, limit 1 and that also has the lightswitch "featured" as true. Here is what I have.

```
        {% set featuredEntry = craft.entries({
            section:            'resources',
            orderBy:            'postDate desc',
            limit:              1,
            where:              {'featured': 1},

        }) %}
```

Also to note I'm on craft 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just query for the field value directly [How to use Element Queries](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/#param-value-syntax)

```twig
{% set featuredEntry = craft.entries({
    section:  ['resources'],
    orderBy:  {postDate: SORT_DESC},
    limit:    1,
    featured: 1,
}).all() %}
```

Comment: We were posting at the same time. Thanks again for your help!